# Referencing code-behind properties on .aspx page?

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, code-behind

On a .aspx page, what is the best way to link a server control's property to a property of the page class (its code-behind)?  The only way that I have read about is to use databinding:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" Text='<%# Me.SomePropOfMine %>' />
```

and then call `Me.txt.DataBind()` or `Me.Databind()` from the codebehind.  Is there any way of establishing this relationship on the .aspx page alone, or simplifying the process if you have many controls to bind (without binding the entire page)?

Comment: Did you manage t get this working as wished ?

Comment: Sort of: prior to reading your answer, I'd done so by creating a simple custom control: it inherited `TextBox` and invoked `Me.DataBind` during its `PreRender` event. This gave me the effect I was looking for, but obviously wasn't an ideal solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can `Databind()` entire `Me` or a container control (you can add a `PlaceHolder` control around your desired controls also). because `DataBind()` goes recursively on Child controls.

A better approach if you don't need DataBinding except for this is to use Code Expression Binder

http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/09/The-CodeExpressionBuilder.aspx

This allows you to use `<%$ Code: Me.Property %>` instead of  `<%# Me.Property %>`.

For more about expression builders in general if you don't know them at all check this intro post:
https://web.archive.org/web/20210304125044/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/022509-1.aspx

Note that `<%= Me.Property %>` will NOT work on web controls like `<asp:TextBox ...` and such...

**P.S.**

The only drawback with `Code` expression builder is that you get no intellisense. I usually work around this by writing `<%= Me.TestSomething %>` inside the markup to get my intellisense, and then replace `<%=` with `<%$ Code:` when done. Annoying, but if you don't want to go the DataBind() route (and you shouldn't cause it may conflict with existing real data binding you want to do. Trust me, trying to make those work is hell), then this is the way to go.

Comment: ah excellent—I didn't want to use `Me.DataBind` because it's a master page and doing so interferes with certain child-pages, but databinding to a placeholder would work. This expression-builder method looks even more promising though, I will check that out. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

There are two things:

1. Use <%= instead of <%# if you want to read the values of some variables.
2. You can use Page.DataBind() to bind all the controls in the page.

Answer (score 0):

If I would ever actually need to do this, I would use [CodeExpressionBuilder](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/09/The-CodeExpressionBuilder.aspx).

But question is - why do you want to set properties in markup and not in code behind? If they are dynamic and related to logic (and probably they are), then you should set them in code behind even if that looks unconvenient - that would keep logic in one place and markup in other.

Comment: The reason I don't like using the code-behind is that it's so dependant on the load sequence -- I can't manipulate a page's controls prior to the `Page.Init` event, but one control needs to access a certain field during its (the control's) `Init`, which occurs prior to that of the page. I'd rather just show the control how to get the data, than to actually give it the data, for reasons like this.